# java - printing out "bank account" info using a toString method

Tags: java

So for an assignment I have to read from a input file that is formated as so: 
Miller <--- last name
William <---first name 
00001  <--- account ID
891692 06   <--- account balance
 
These four lines represent an "account". From a main method I have to call from another class called account and run a method in that class called toString() 
toString() is supposed to print out those four lines in this format: 
**00001, Miller, William, $891692.06**

Here's what I have in my main method so far:

```
 int count = 1;
    while(read.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = read.nextLine();
            account.toString(nextLine);
        if(count %4==0) {
            vector.addAccount(nextLine);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

And this is whats in my toString method:

```
public String toString(String line) {
 for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
  line = info[i]; 
    position++;
     }
     return System.out.println(info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3]);
}
```

In toString I'm getting an error with the return statement and also I need to format info[3](which should end up being the account balance) so that it will be in dollar notation when it prints like: $00.00

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your toString method is messed up.  What does the info array do?  What does the position variable do?  why would you overwrite line when you just passed it in?  I'm guessing you will have to rethink your toString method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating Nambari's tip, you should try it as the following code:

```
int count = 1;
while(read.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextLine = read.nextLine();
        System.out.println(account.toString(nextLine));
    if(count %4==0) {
        vector.addAccount(nextLine);
    }
    count++;
}
```

And the toString method:

```
public String toString(String line) {
   for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
      line = info[i]; 
      position++;
   }
   return info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't `return` `System.out.println(...);`

Your `return` statement should be something like below:

```
return info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with this code. The first is the obvious compile error

```
return System.out.println(info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3]);
```

You should return a `String` but a call to `System.out.println` does not return anything. It prints a `String` on the console. What you need is

```
return info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3];
```

The second is the implementation of your `toString` method. I think the `toString` to what your assignment refers is the standard `toString` method inherited from `Object`. Meaning you would have an `Account` class where you either pass the contents of the file in the constructor, or let the `Account` class parse the file. The values read from the file are then stored in fields, and in the `toString` method you return those in the correct form. Something like

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
  //loop over file and create Account instances
  Account account = new Account( lastName, firstName, ... );
}

public class Account{
  private String lastName, firstName;
  public Account( String lastName, String firstName, ... ){
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return lastName + ", " + firstName ... ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a `print` statement from `toString`, but a string itself.

Just change your `return` statement to : -

```
return info[2]+", "+info[0]+", "+info[1]+", "+info[3];
```